# Kendo UI Combobox sample code is not working in jsp

Tags: jsp, kendo-ui

I working on Kendo UI first time in my project, I am trying to create combobox using their sample code [here](https://demos.telerik.com/jsp-ui/combobox/template). Same code is working in html but if add same code in jsp its not working, result in jsp I am not able to see list values.

[image]

I have one more question, can I import kendo ui library and bootstrap library together? will it cause any conflicts?

Many thanks in advance!

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/KendoUI/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/KendoUI/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/KendoUI/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="./assets/KendoUI/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/KendoUI/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
  <input id="dropdownlist" />

<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <table>
        <tr class="combo-tr">
            <td class="combo-td">${band}</td>
            <td class="combo-td">${song}</td>
        <td class="combo-td">${album}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
</script>


<script>    
        var data = [
            { id: 1, band: "Iron Maiden", song: "Wasted Years", album: "Ed Hunter" },
            { id: 2, band: "Metallica", song: "Enter Eandman", album: "Metallica" },
            { id: 3, band: "Mr. Big", song: "Seven Impossible Days", album: "Japandemonium" },
            { id: 4, band: "Unknown Band", song: "Some Song", album: "The Album" }
        ];

        $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
            optionLabel: "Please select a band...",
            dataSource: data,
            dataTextField: "band",
            dataValueField: "id",
            autoWidth: true,
            headerTemplate: '<table><tr class="combo-tr"><td class="combo-hd-td">Band</td><td class="combo-hd-td">Song</td><td class="combo-hd-td">Album</td></tr></table>',
            template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
        });

</script>

<style>  
    .combo-td{
        width:150px;
    }

    .combo-hd-td{
        width:150px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your browser Developer Tools network tab.  Are any of the libraries not loading ? Check the computed CSS of the drop down elements, are there any specifiers getting overridden by non-kendo stylesheets ?

Comment: @Richard I didn't add any extra library. All Kendo ui libraries are loading without any problem.

Comment: What version of Kendo UI are the assets ?

Comment: @Richard Recent one I have downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The empty area in the drop down below the column headers appears to be four rows worth of space and suggests one possibility is a CSS issue, perhaps `visibility: hidden`

Your templates render visibly in a [Kendo Dojo snippet](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/oqitokeb) using library version "2018 R2 SP1" and MS Edge browser.

However, the template seems a little overkill -- for each data item you are asking Kendo to create a list item (the basis of the realized dropdownlist) that is itself a table.

Try a simpler template (also shown in the Dojo), such as

```
<script id="template2-header" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <div class='ddl-header k-item'>
    <div class='ddl-band'>Band</div>
    <div class='ddl-song'>Song</div>
    <div class='ddl-album'>Album</div>
  </div>
</script>

<script id="template2" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <div class='ddl-item'>
    <div class='ddl-band'>${band}</div>
    <div class='ddl-song'>${song}</div>
    <div class='ddl-album'>${album}</div>
  </div>
</script>
```

and use CSS to set the column widths.

See kendo demo [customizing templates](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/template) for additional examples.

Comment: Thanks @Richard for quick response, but Its still not working for me.

Comment: Do the Dojo drop down examples work ?  Do you have any browser add-ons running ? Are there any developer tool console messages ?  If the demos and dojos work, but your specific jsp pages don't I would suspect issues with your cache, or server configuration with regards to Kendo..

Comment: You might also try removing the pages DOCTYPE